# ConcurrentModificationException in foreach loop

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, concurrentmodification

In my code:

```
    Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<String> it = c.iterator();
    c.add("Hello");
    System.out.println(it.next());
```

Exception occures, because my collection changed after iterator created.

But what about in this code:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    for (Integer integer : list) {     // Exception is here
        if (integer.equals(2)) {
            list.remove(integer);
        }
    }
```

Why exception occured?

In second  code, i did changes in my collection before for-each loop.

Comment: What do you thing remove() does, if it doesn't modify the collection?

Comment: for-each uses iterator.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second loop, it's the same reason - you are removing an element from the list.

To remove elements from a `List` while looping through it, either use standard old-fashioned for loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
```

and remove list items inside that loop or use a `ListIterator` to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2):

Exception is because you are iterating as well as removing the element from the list

```
 for (Integer integer : list) {     // Exception is here because you are iterating and also removing the elements of same list here
        if (integer.equals(2)) {
            list.remove(integer);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are also changing your collection inside the for-each loop:

```
  list.remove(integer);
```

If you need to remove elements while iterating, you either keep track of the indices you need to delete and delete them after the for-each loop finishes, or you use a Collection that allows concurrent modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use    [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), it's not very efficient, but solves the ConcurrentModificationException, and you can use safely the remove method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest way to never get ConcurrentModificationExceptions if you need to remove elements while iterating using the better syntax:

```
// utility method somewhere
public static < T > Iterable< T > remainingIn( final Iterator< T > itT ) {
    return new Iterable< T >() {
        @Override
        public Iterator< T > iterator() {
            return itT;
        }
    }
}

// usage example
Iterator< Integer > itI = list.iterator();
for ( Integer integer : remainingIn( itI ) ) {
    if ( integer.equals( 2 ) ) {
        itI.remove();
    }
}
```